# How do I add default value as same from another column in Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `questions` table in my database, in which I have a column of `question_title`, now I have added a column `question_slug`, which will contain the  **question's slug URL**, so how I set `question_slug` default value as `question_title` in Laravel Migration, I need this all because I have questions saved in the database so I have run `php artisan make:migration add_column_to_questions --table=questions` now I have this code:

```
Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('question_slug')->default();
});
```

Comment: You need this to be unique first,  second, you have to make a script to generate unique url using the `question_text` and some timestamp. But as you already have some questions saved in the database, you can just add `question_slug` as a text with initially nullable and run your script to generate and save the `question_slug` based on the `question_title` after that create another migration to update the `question_slug` to unique.

Comment: you want to add all existing question_title to question_slug, or when you create new question_title put the default value of slug as it ?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih no no if there is any way to fetch the question's Title then I will apply this `strtoslug()` to convert it into slug then I will save this into variable and then will assign it to `default($question_slug)`...

Comment: your strtoslug is class or just a function please ?

Comment: `strtoslug` is built-in func of laravel

Comment: there is no function like this name within laravel documentation

Comment: sorry it's `str_slug()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182364/discussion-between-thamer-belfkih-and-usman-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, create a new migration and put this code within it:

> connections_string :  it's within web/config/database.php file
>   configuration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class NameOfUrMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('question_slug')->default();
        });

         $questions = DB::connection('connections_string')->table('questions')->get();

         foreach($questions as $question)
         {
            $question->question_slug = str_slug($question->question_title);
            $question->save();
         }


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns), `default()` is used to `Declare a default value for a column`.
That means the value that gets inserted by default in a field if you do not provide a value for it in the `insert` query.

The `default()` cannot help you achieve what you need here.
What you could do is create a new migration class with a raw query in the `up()` method which will update the value of `question_slug` with the value of `question_title`.

something like this:

```
public function up()
{
    $sql = "UPDATE `questions` SET `question_slug` = `question_title` WHERE 1;"; 
    //add filtering conditions if you don't want ALL records updated
    DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
}
```

Make sure you also create a corresponding `down()` method for the `rollback`